# Could not move data in PHP

Tags: php, html

I'm encountering a problem where I can't upload my videos. It produce this error: Could not move data.

```
<?php

//phpunfo();
echo '<br />';
echo <<<_END
<div id = "sec1">
<h1>Video Upload</h1>
<br />
<form method='post' action='Upload.php' 
enctype='multipart/form-data'>
Select File: <input type='file' name='filename' size='50' />
<input type='submit' value='Upload' />
</form>
<br />
</div>
_END;

if (isset($_FILES['filename'])) {
$name = "videos//" . $_FILES['filename']['name'];
if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES['filename']['tmp_name'], $name)) {
    include 'DO_Files.php';
    $file = new DO_File();

    $type = $_FILES['filename']['type'];
    $size = $_FILES['filename']['size'];

    $file->FileName = $name;
    $file->FileSize = $size;
    $file->Type = $type;

    if ($file->save()) {
        $fileId = $file->getFileIdFromName();

        if ($fileId) {
            echo "<h1> Thank you </h1><p>Image stored "
            . "successfully</p>";
            echo "<p>Upload image '$name'</p><br /><img src='$name' "
            . "height='200' width='200'/>";
            echo '<br><a href="Display.php?id=' . $fileId .
            '">Display image ' . $file->FileName . '</a>';
        } else
            echo '<p class="error">Error retrieving file '
            . 'information</p>';
    }
    else {
        echo '<p class="error"> Oh dear. There was a database '
        . 'error</p>';
    }
} else {
    $error_array = error_get_last();
    echo "<p class='error'>Could not move the file</p>";
    if (!is_null($error_array)) {
        foreach ($error_array as $err) {
            echo $err;
        }
    }
}
}
```

Comment: `$name = "videos//` right here, why do you have double `/`  in the path?

Comment: `videos//`? Why two slashes? And note that your code is dangerous. `['name']` in $_FILES is the filename provided by the user, and is under their control. they can put in pathing information, causing your code to overwrite ANY file on your server. And testing `isset($_FILES)` is pointless. that will STILL be set even if the upload failed. you need to check the `['error']` parameter.

Answer (score 0):

check this

```
$name = "videos/" . $_FILES['filename']['name'];
```

Answer (score 0):

The destination folder for your video looks strange.

In most cases a `//` in no problem, but it would be better to use only one slash to divide folders.
I also would recommend to use a full path, if `videos` is next to our PHP file, you can write:

```
 $name = __DIR__.'/videos/'.$_FILES['filename']['name'];
```

And you have to make sure that PHP has the rights to write in the folder `videos`! (You can check this with [`is_writable()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.is-writable.php))

On windows you maybe have to write `\\` (2 backslash) instead of `/`.

Comment: Our teacher supplied us with this script. We essentially used it to retrieve data from our university database (network). That might explain the file path syntax.